# How to mount a drive from command line

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I normally mount my drives just by opening it from filesystem. It automatically mount when I click on a drive. But I wanted to mount a drive from command line. I did ran this command

```
sudo mount -o exec /media/john/Study
```

but I get this error

```
mount: /dev/sda8 already mounted or /media/john/Study busy
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda8 is already mounted on /media/john/Study
```

This error show when I already mounted the Study drive by opening it from filesystem. But if I unmount the drive and then run the same command I get this error

```
mount: can't find /media/john/Study in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

How can I mount a drive from commandline?

This is very annoying to mount each time I restart or start my pc. A bonus would be if you could tell me how can I automatically mount my drives automatically when I start my pc.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to permanently mount it, you must make an entry for it in `/etc/fstab` file like this:

```
/dev/sda8    /media/john/Study   ext4     defaults    0     0
```

Second, if you just want to mount it from the command line each time, then use the full command, indicating the drive and mount point.

```
mount /dev/sda8 /media/john/Study
```

Comment: Now I get this error fuse: failed to access mountpoint /media/bcc/Study: No such file or directory

Comment: ok then make the directory /media/bcc/Study first

Comment: This gives error "mount: can't find /media/bcc/Study in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab"